# Cluster points in each polygon into n parts

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, point, clustering

I am working on adding 2000 random points to each of 2 polygons and then clustering the points in those polygons into 4 clusters for each polygon. When I apply [`ST_ClusterKMeans()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterKMeans.html) in PostGIS, it divides the entirety of points (2000 points in each of 2 polygons) into 4 clusters spread across 2 polygons (Figure 1). However, I would expect there to be 2000 points divided into 4 clusters for *each* polygon.

How can I apply `ST_ClusterKMeans()` to each polygon so that each polygon has 4 clusters of points?

---

```
CREATE TABLE sample_pnts AS
  SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_GeneratePoints(geom, 2000))).geom AS geom
  FROM sample_polys;

CREATE TABLE sample_pnts_clustered AS
  SELECT geom, ST_ClusterKMeans(geom, 4) over () AS cluster
  FROM sample_pnts;
```

**Figure 1**

[image]

Comment: It's a window function; you should be able to `PARTITION BY <poly_id>`. Note, though, that it generates a cluster id sequence starting from 0 *per `<poly_id>`*, so you'll have to identify a cluster by both ids.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `ST_ClusterKMeans` has been re-implemented as *[Window Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tutorial-window.html)*, it is trivial to `PARTITION BY` an arbitrary category definition, and have the function work on each window individually.

`ST_ClusterKMeans` will use a `0` based sequence for each window it operates in, meaning that the result will have cluster ids `0..n` **for each (hierarchy of) partition key(s)** used in the `PARTITION BY` expression; in order to distinguish clusters, it is necessary to reference them by (all) the partition key(s) plus cluster id.

To get cluster for each set of points in a polygon, assuming you have them assigned a `poly_id`:

```
WITH
    polys(poly_id, geom) AS (
        VALUES  (1, 'POLYGON((0 0, 0 5, 5 5, 5 0, 0 0))'::GEOMETRY),
                (2, 'POLYGON((10 10, 10 15, 15 15, 15 10, 10 10))'::GEOMETRY)
    )
SELECT  polys.poly_id,
        ST_ClusterKMeans(pts.geom, 4) OVER(PARTITION BY polys.poly_id) AS cluster_id,
        pts.geom
FROM    polys,
        LATERAL ST_Dump(ST_GeneratePoints(polys.geom, 1000, 1)) AS pts
ORDER BY
        1, 2
;
```

[image: ST_ClusterKMeans on point sets, partitioned by polygon id.]

To reference individual clusters, use the partition key `poly_id` plus `cluster_id`, e.g. to get point counts per cluster:

```
SELECT poly_id,
       cluster_id,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   <above_query_or_derived_table>
GROUP BY
       poly_id, cluster_id
ORDER BY
       poly_id, cluster_id
;
```

returns

```
 poly_id | cluster_id | count 
---------+------------+-------
       1 |          0 |   252
       1 |          1 |   246
       1 |          2 |   253
       1 |          3 |   249
       2 |          0 |   252
       2 |          1 |   246
       2 |          2 |   253
       2 |          3 |   249
(8 rows)
```

---

This works best, and most performant, on base type partition keys (e.g. `INT`), but if necessary you can use the `geom` column to partition by.